# Advanced Security Permissions for Shared Drive

Tags: windows, file-permissions, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have a large, shared drive of folders that are automatically created when a client is added to software that we use. I want to allow users to access the folders on the top level of the drive but not write, edit, delete or move any of these (read only). I also want them to be able to access the folders underneath the top folders in the drive with full read/write privileges.

For example:

```
 Drive X: (shared drive)
 |
 +-- 1. Top Folder 1 (read only)
 |      |
 |      +-- lower folder/files (read/write)  
 |      |
 |      +-- lower folder/files (read/write)  
 |
 |
 +-- 2. Top Folder 2 (read only)
 |      |
 |      +-- lower folder/files (read/write)  
 |      |
 |      +-- lover folder/files (read/write)
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal with what I call *Top Level Folder Permissions*.

### Summary

- On the drive's root, grant **Read** permissions to your users which flow down to all subfolders and files throughout the drive.
- On each "Top Level" folder in the root drive, apply special permissions that grant users **Modify** permissions to the folders' contents (all files and subfolders) but *not* to the Top Level folders themselves.

### Steps to Implement

1. On the Root drive, grant `Everyone` (or another group of your choice) standard **Read** permissions
2. Optionally, on the Root drive, consider ensuring `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` are granted **Full Control**, then remove all other permissions (e.g. those granted to `CREATOR OWNER` or `Users`)
3. On each Top-Level folder:

   - Grant the `Everyone` group **Modify** permissions, then edit that permission assignment in the Advanced Security Settings to apply to **Subfolders and files only**
   - Still in Advanced Security Settings make another entry granting the `Everyone` group the following specific permissions and apply these to **This folder only**:

     - Create files / write data
     - Create folders / append data
4. Repeat step #3 for *each* Top Level folder

### How it Works

The effect of #1 is to grant your security group the ability to Read everything on the drive.

The effect of #3 is to grant your security group the ability to Modify all child objects of your Top Level folders *without* granting them permission to modify the Top Level folders themselves.  This isn't sufficient to permit them to Create anything in the Top Level folders, hence the extra explicit 'create' permissions.

### Apply to Many Top Level Folders

The permissions of step #3 above must be applied to *each* "Top Level" folder. This can be time consuming if you have many folders. These permissions can be applied to all subfolders in the drive's root using the [FOR](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) and [ICACLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) run in an Elevated Command Prompt:

```
For /D %f In (C:\*.*) Do ICACLS "%f" /grant "Everyone":(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
For /D %f In (C:\*.*) Do ICACLS "%f" /grant "Everyone":(WD,AD)
```

As shown, these two commands will modify all subfolders in `C:\` to grant the permissions outlined in step #3 to the `Everyone` group.  Modify these two elements to suit your needs. *Test first before running on a production system!*

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much @Twisty, only annoyance is there are thousands of "Top Level Folders" that need to be restricted to read only with subfolder read/write permissions. I would imagine that this would be done quicker with the cmd prompt.

Comment: Script provided in updated answer. No more annoyance! Please upvote if this gets you to where you want to be!